# Structures export data for specific name

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures

That is the structure that I created:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;


struct Students
{
    char first_name[10];
    char last_name[10];
    char country[20];


};
void main()
{
    Students array;
    int n, i;
    cin >> n;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "Name:";
        cin >> array.first_name;
        cout << "Last Name:";
        cin >> array.last_name;
        cout << "Country:";
        cin >> array.country;

    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << array.first_name << " ";
        cout << array.last_name << " ";
        cout << array.country << " ";


    }
    system("pause");


}
```

What I can't do is ... For example, I enter the name John (in this line)

```
cout << "Name:";
cin >> array.first_name;
```

And I have to write code that once I enter John (for example)
displays all information about him: last name, country. And when I enter country to export: first name, last name. Maybe I don't explain it properly. Because my english is bad. Maybe that's the reason that i can't find specific information or similar examples.

```
Ouput example:
Name:John
Last Name: Doe
Country: England

And that's the part that i can't do:

/Info about student/
Enter Name for check:
John

and here the output must be:
Last Name: Doe
Country: England
```

Comment: You probably meant that the 2nd `cin` isn't allowing you to enter anything?

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit Yes, this isn't correct? Maybe I should use int?

Comment: @aspaar321: Definitely you should use `int`! `main` returns `int`, always and forever.

Comment: How is 'system("pause");' related to the problem. Omit this stuff even from your real code!

Answer (score 2):

You need a container where you store all your students: I recommend to use `std::vector`.

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<Students> students;
```

Read your data into a local variable and append it to your container.

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    Students student;
    cout << "Name:";
    cin >> student.first_name;
    cout << "First name:";
    cin >> student.last_name;
    cout << "Country:";
    cin >> student.country;

    students.push_back( student ); // <- append student to array of students
}
```

Iterate through your container to print all students

```
/* 
 1. students.begin(); is a function that starts at the first value in 
the array of data that you want to go through
 2. students.end(); marks the end
 3. the type **auto** is used, to automatically get the type for your variable, 
it is more efficient since there will be no conversion and you don't have to 
worry about type spelling errors
*/

for ( auto it = students.begin(); it != students.end(); it++ )
// for ( std::vector<Students>::iterator it = students.begin(); it != students.end(); it++ ) // auto <-> std::vector<Students>::iterator
{
    cout << it->first_name << " ";
    cout << it->last_name << " ";
    cout << it->country << " ";
}
```

This code is similar to the above:

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < students.size(); i++ )
{
    cout << students[i].first_name << " ";
    cout << students[i].last_name << " ";
    cout << students[i].country << " ";
}
```

If you like to find a student by its name you have to use `strcmp` to compare names.

```
for ( auto it = students.begin(); it != students.end(); it++ )
{
    if ( strcmp( it->first_name, searchname ) == 0 )
    {
      ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Questions will appear, "what is auto", "what is begin()", "what is end()", "what is ->". If we tell others to use things they don't understand, then they will never learn.

Answer (score 0):

```
Students array;
```

You made just one, single student.
You have to make an array, static, alocated with new, vector, or sth else.
For now change it to

```
Students array[10];
```

and intput it:

```
cin >> array[i].first_name;
```

Comment: I'm not sure but the number of students is determined by n. For example, if I type 3 for n I will have three students.

Comment: @aspaar321 Then you should use std::vector
`std::vector<Strudents> array;`
and use "push_back" at the beginning loop iteration, then input like i posted.
`array.push_back(Students{0,0,0});`